# JavaScript import JSON data - Loop to sort by long/lat location

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am reading a json file which looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "name":"Mark Brown",
        "location":{
            "lat":50.72423653147234,
            "lon":-0.6552093628538713
            }
    },

    {
        "name":"Nina Wright",
        "location":{
            "lat":51.00351657212984,
            "lon":0.4104543851588729
        }
    }

]
```

Then I have a loop that will display the data in a list on my page.

```
$.getJSON(JsonFile, function(List){

  var div = document.getElementById('list');

  for( var i = 0; i < List.length;i++ ) { 

      div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<li>'+List[i].name+'</li>';

  }


});
```

This will append the list to the `<ul id="List"></ul>`

This all works great but what I need to do is to order the data **by location** in DESC order before appending the data to my page.

How can I do this?

Comment: what do you mean by location? first by lat then by lon?

Comment: You'll probably need to write a custom comparator function and use javascript's built in sort. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort for more details

Comment: Basically inside the loop I'm using var result = checkDistance(fixedlat,fixedlon,data[i].location.lat,data[i].location.lon);
            if(result <= 20){ ...then I get the list but I need to order then results by location in some order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a sorting callback with the delta of the distance.

```
data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (
        checkDistance(fixedlat, fixedlon, a.location.lat, a‌​.location.lon) -
        checkDistance(fixedlat, fixedlon, b.location.lat, b‌​.location.lon)
    );
});
```